# Vector push_back() fails when compiling with CMake and MinGW Makefiles

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile

I've been searching all over the internet for a solution to this problem, however there is no good information about the origin of this problem. In essence, the program fails to run whenever I execute any vector-related function such as resize() or initializing the vector with a given size.

This is the current project structure of this example:

```
example_project
│   CMakeLists.txt 
|
└───src
│   |    main.cpp
│   
└───build
    │   Example.exe
    │   ...
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```cpp
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.0)

project(Example)

# Retrieve all source files
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp)

add_executable(Example ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Test\n";
  
  // Example code
  std::vector<int> exampleVector;
  exampleVector.push_back(1);

  // Same applies to any other vector operation
  // Ex: std::vector<int> exampleVector(10);

  return 0;
}
```

This code runs fine when compiling with CMake for Visual Studio via `cmake ..` from the build directory via the terminal. However, I want to build this project without any IDE, thus I want to directly compile it with CMake while still being able to use another text editor. Thus I assumed "MinGW Makefiles" to be a good candidate.

**Building and running the application:**

```cpp
> cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"  -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON  ..
> make
```

The above commands execute without any errors. Then running Example.exe yields:
[image]

I am rather inexperienced when it comes to CMake so I would appreciate any feedback on a better solution for building the project. But the bottom-line is that I want to use CMake for managing large projects without having to use any IDE or solution-file systems such as MSVC, just the terminal for building and running the application. The vector standard header seems to be the problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should first figure out how to compile and link on the command-line *without* CMake.  That way, you will be able to figure out what you're missing.  Adding CMake to the mix just adds another layer of complexity.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am aware of g++ and outputing object files and so such, I in fact am aware of compiling without CMake. However this is just a small example program. I tried compiling with g++ -o example.exe main.cpp and I get the same error message.

Comment: Well, start with why that program doesn't execute properly using a simple command line.  This isn't a CMake issue.  It's like saying that your car key fob doesn't open the door, but even when using the regular car key, the door won't open.

Comment: test.exe looks like is unable to find mingw runtime. Add required dll files to .exe location.

Comment: Heads up, your `file(GLOB_RECURSE ...etc)` in your `CMakeLists.txt` just returns one file. You can skip this and just say `add_executable(Example ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp)`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I like that anecdote, however the bottom-line is the same: the door doesn't open. What I am grasping at with this post is a solution for CMake, i.e. missing libs or such and how I would go about including them with CMake. In order to fix the door in the first place I must first find what is actually the core of the issue.

Comment: @273K In that case I wonder which DLL files are required? Taking a look inside `Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64` I can't seem to find any required DLLs other than the lib folder.

Comment: The required dlls for mingw should be in the compilers bin folder. For me that is in `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` since I use msys2 to provide my mingw binaries and manage library dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

It seems that the problem had to do with static linking of necessary libraries. Thus the solution I found was to include one of the static flags for `g++` such as `-static`, `-static-libstdc++`, etc. To tell CMake to do this automatically upon compilation I just added this as a flag:

```cpp
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libstdc++")
```

That being said I still have so many questions regarding the need to actually do this and if this is even the preferred solution or use-case of static linking.